Add imageList to imagListBoxControl
private void AddAutomobileForm_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < imageList1.Images.Count; i++)
    {
        imageListBoxControl1.ImageList = imageList1.Images[i];
    }
}

Hello, everyone.have a good day.
I'm keeping a number of photos in the imagList control.
I was wondering, Does anyone know how to pass the photos to imageListBoxControl, which is a DevExpress component?

You are not trying to add a list but one of the images. Also: what is an ImageListBox Control? Are you using DevExpress? If so you should tag it!!

Yes, I use DevExpress.
Well how can I add a list of images to this control.

I have added the needed tag but I don't use or know DevExpress. I think you need to know if yur control will be data bound.

You should also set the ImageList property of imageListBoxControl1 to the imageList1 :
for (int i=0; i < imageList1.Images.Count; i++)
{
    imageListBoxControl1.Items.Add($"item {i}",i);
}
imageListBoxControl1.ImageList = imageList1;

This makes the imageListBoxControl with a text as item number for each item.
If you want to set the text to the image name:
for (int i=0; i < imageList1.Images.Count; i++)
{
    imageListBoxControl1.Items.Add(imageList1.Images.Keys[i],i);
}
imageListBoxControl1.ImageList = imageList1;

